# Get the same random numbers with a seed using different coding languajes

Tags: java, python, r, c, random

I need a function to generate random numbers from a seed across multiple computers using different languajes.
I want to know if there is a common function in the libraries of C, Python, Java and R that, using the same seed, gives the same random numbers.
If not, what is the best option to achieve this?

Comment: Use one language's RNG and interface with that language from the other languages.

Comment: You can write your own PRNG function (there are plenty of algorithms to be found) and implement it in each language you need.

Comment: If it were me and I wanted to avoid wasting precious development time and effort, I would get an **existing** library that properly implements the same algorithm (MT or LCG as suggested in the dupe). I would not make bridges between languages or start writing my own (possibly buggy) implementations unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Kayaman Unless someone has done the work for you and interfaced the library with all languages (that's possible), you'll have to do that yourself. I don't think you will find that for the Mersenne Twister (because there are so many different versions of it).

Comment: @Roland I didn't mean the same *library*. I meant the same algorithm. The MT discrepancy is discussed in the dupe, but it should be a lot less work to get 4 libraries for 4 languages and verify that they use the same algorithm and provide the same results than writing your own things. At least for the very common languages given in the question.

Comment: @Kayaman Personally, I'd think it would be easier (and require less knowledge about RNGs) to interface all languages mentioned by OP with R than conclusively testing and comparing four libraries. But to each their own.